# ssh warning message missing file issue

Tags: centos, ssh, centos6, centos6.4, warning

When I log into ssh (centos 6.5 64bit)

```
Can't locate warnings.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/share/perl5/local/lib.pm line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/local/lib.pm line 2.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

su -
Can't locate warnings.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/share/perl5/local/lib.pm line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl5/local/lib.pm line 2.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to determine what perl script is trying to run, then either fix it or disable it.  This has nothing to do with ssh.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is some kind of a perl script that is being run upon every SSH login, and the script is requiring a newer version of perl than is installed on the server. Check your `sshd` config, `/etc/profile` or `bashrc` files to see what could be being sourced every time you connect to a shell.